# Referencing another element in golang's GORM

Tags: database, sqlite, go, go-gorm

I have a database that contains items and clients. Each item may belong to a single client. Right now, my structs are:

```
type Item struct {
    Id        int64
    Barcode   string `sql:"not null;unique"`
    Name      string
    ...
    ClientId  int64
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

type Client struct {
    Id   int64
    Name string
    Telephone int64
}
```

This works wonderfully with GORM's `Related()` function. However, I'd like to have Facebook-style structs returned, like this:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Barcode": "AA4854845",
    "Name": "100m 3.5mm",
    "Model": "Random",
    "Description": "test",
    "Status": "new",
    "BoxId": 0,
    "Client": {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "John",
        "Telephone": 123456789
    },
    "CreatedAt": "2014-06-05T16:59:35.639115765Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "2014-06-05T16:59:35.639119134Z"
}
```

This can be done by adding a `Client Client` object to `Item`. But then I end up with

```
"ClientId": 0,
"Client": {
    "Id": 0,
    ...
},
```

which is nasty. Am I missing something that would help me solve this?

Comment: can you add your code? Only struct definition and log seems not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the preload feature, check it out: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm#preloading-eager-loading

Comment: That looks awesome, but won't I end up with two fields?: one named "user" and another one as "user_id". If not, this is perfect!